# Start Program with delay if no user input

Tags: google-chrome, batch-file, console

Hello can someone help me to improve my batchfile? I want to delay the start of Chrome. After a periode of time "delay" chrome start with the given url. So now i want to check while delay time if someone enter any key. If input -> do nothing and close batch else -> start program.

Here is my current script:

```
@echo off
set "delay=5"

timeout /T %delay%
start chrome -kiosk https://test123
exit
```

Comment: `choice` can do that - but not with "any key" If you're okay with "press Y now to start browser", it's a good and stable option. See `choice /?` for options like default-choice, timeout, text, keys, etc.

Comment: Seems your script works perfect. You should however  remove the "exit". When called by a batch, the batch will end anyways. When called from an alread open commandline window, it will close that window, which may not be intended.

Comment: Thank you guys for respons. I used choice command and it works very well.